# getStyleClass().add() has no effect after i moved my css files

Tags: css, javafx-2, javafx

I'm just refactoring my program and due to sorting files in seperate folder etc... I recognized, that some css style classes are ignored.

So for example: i added a style class to a view and a second style class to a label, which is a child of the view (view.getStyleClass().add("myView");).
This worked pretty well until now. Now the style class of the view is applied, but not the style class of the label. Both style classes are in the very same css file

Has anybody an idea please?

code example:

```
StyleManager.getInstance().addUserAgentStylesheet(cssFilePath);
view.getStyleClass().add("myView"); //will be applied
...
msgLabel.getStyleClass().add("myLabel"); //has no effect
msgLabel.setId("messageId");
```

CSS snippet:

```
.myView {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#44bbff 0%, #0063d3 100%);
    -fx-background-radius: 10;
    -fx-border-style: none;
    -fx-padding: 0 30 0 0;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, #d9d9d9, 10, 0, 2, 2);
}

.myView:pressed {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#1b82da 0%, #176dbc 100%);
}

.myLabel {
    -fx-font-size: 32px;
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, #223377, 10, 0, 1, 1);
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
```

Update: When i change my labels style class to following code, the font size is applied but not the text fill, effect.

```
.label .myLabel {
    -fx-font-size: 32px;
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, #223377, 10, 0, 1, 1);
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: make sure you have only one css class in your project and make "Clean and Build"

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you! But still, is there a way to have multiple css files ? So is it a problem caused by the moment each file is loaded? What if I write some type of asset manager which loads all css file at program start?

Comment: No, you can have multiple css files. I asked just to make sure you didn't forget to delete older version of your refactored file. And "Clean/Build" is required to make sure your refactored css gets to actual jar/class location.